# Error publishing UWP with Mysql.dll in WINDOWS STORE using Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, uwp, windows-store-apps

I'm having the following error while posting to the Windows store (microsoft).

> API CreateFileW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application
>   type. MySql.Data.dll calls this API.
>
> API MapViewOfFile in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.dll calls this API.
>
> API OpenFileMappingW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this
>   application type. MySql.Data.dll calls this API.
>
> API AcquireCredentialsHandleW in secur32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.dll calls this API.
>
> API CompleteAuthToken in secur32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.dll calls this API.
>
> API DeleteSecurityContext in secur32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.dll calls this API.
>
> API FreeCredentialsHandle in secur32.dll is not supported for this application type. MySql.Data.dll calls this API.
>
> API InitializeSecurityContextW in secur32.dll is not supported for
>   this application type. MySql.Data.dll calls this API.
>
> API QueryContextAttributesW in secur32.dll is not supported for this
>   application type. MySql.Data.dll calls this API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory - the APIs used by `MySQL.Data.Dll` are not supported for UWP.

You have a few options if you want to publish to the Microsoft Store:

1. If possible, look for a UWP-compatible version of MySQL. Some of those API failures can be trivially replaced with newer API calls, and others probably don't make sense for an app-local database.

   - We are always trying to improve compatibility with existing code, but right now we can't / don't support all these APIs.
2. If you can't get a UWP-compliant version of MySQL, try another database like SQLite. SQLite is now [built-in to Windows](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/06/using-sqlite-databases-uwp-apps/) and has a UWP-compatible version you can ship in your app if you need to support Windows versions before 14393
3. If you **must** use MySQL and can't get a UWP-compliant version, you could try publishing as a Desktop Bridge app

   - This requires special permission though, and right now you can't mix legacy API calls like this and modern XAML UI - they have to be in separate processes.